# Dictionary ContainsKey & Value in same Item

Tags: c#

I need to check if my dictionary contains both values on the same line .  For example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> ServiceLIST = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ServiceLIST.add(ServiceName,ServiceStatus)
//if (ServiceLIST.ContainsKey("testingName") & (ServiceLIST.ContainsKey("testingStatus"))
```

How could I replace that if statement to check if "testingName" && "testingStatus" both exist on the same item in the dictionary?

Comment: What do you mean? Dictionaries don't have "lines". Can you give an example? Also, you probably mean to use "&&", not "&".

Comment: What is the problem with your if?

Comment: Do you mean test if the dictionary contains the key and the value at that key matches the value?

Comment: If I use a foreach loop and messagebox the strings, each item that was added would display as (first value, second value).  I need to check if both strings exist on the same item.  Does that make sense?

Comment: What is the purpose of your construction? Do you use the dictionary *only* in that way, or also in other ways (i.e. retrieving the value for a given key)? If you *only* use it as shown here, you might want to think about combining your two strings into a class or structure, and storing that in a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
if(ServiceLIST.ContainsKey("testingName") 
 && ServiceLIST["testingName"] == "testingStatus")
```

Comment: Well, dont sound TOO surprised. :)  Glad it did.  Selman's is a great answer as well.

Comment: This way is great if you don't care about performance. If you have a performance issue, this way might be a little unefficient because it looks twice for the key in the dictionary. In such case, better use `Contains` with KeyValuePair parameter (see my answer below).

Comment: @MaMazav that entirely depends on his situation.  I would suggest that you read Mr. Atwood's entry on [micro optimizations](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

Comment: @paqogomez I agree, but such code is not necessarily micro optimization like the string example. As you said it entirely depends on the situation. Also, as there is no difference in the readability or time spent between the `ContainsKey` and `Contains(KeyValuePair)` solutions, I would always prefer the more efficient solution, just to get used to the efficient way.

Comment: @MaMazav I dont see how new'ing up a KVP is more efficient.  Could you prove this?  Plus, you'd be doing a reference comparison, not a value comparison.  Your example would fail.

Comment: @MaMazav I just ran our examples back to back, and yours took twice the time.  _Definitely_ not more efficient, I was wrong about the value comparison however.

Comment: @SlopTonio, you can check out [my fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/fT5gzx) if you'd like.  It only shows the execution time difference.  I would guess that if you showed memory usage as well, Ma's would take more memory, less efficient on both counts.

Comment: just checked the fiddle.  I marked this as the best answer due to performance efficiency.

Comment: 1. Your ContainsKey always returns false, thus the second condition is never executed. Change "ServiceName" to "testingName" and you get similar performance to my solution. 2. Allocation on the stack (KVP is a struct) has almost no performance cost. 3. Your example is very special because it demonstrates only single element. Even with two elements I saw a significant difference if you have potential hash collision (I simulated it by EqualityComparer which always returns 0 - ~25% slower), or if you use another indexing method (like SortedDictionary ~ 100%! slower).

Comment: @SlopTonio if you're looking for performance efficiency, here is my fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/7D7Fgc . It demonstrates speedup of about x2 using KVP, in two situations: Hash collision (which is the main concern of performance in Dictionary) and simple SortedDictionary example.

Answer (score 3):

paqogomez's solution works, but it requires you to iterate through the dictionary twice - once to check if the value is in it, another to find what it is mapped to. Usually this isn't a big issue, but if you dictionary is large or if you need this action to work several times, it is a waste.

MaMazav's solution is also good, but as mentiond before, it is less readable and also requires working with KeyValuePairs (which I personally dislike).

The best solution I think is:

```
string mappedValue;
if(ServiceLIST.TryGetValue("testingName", out mappedValue) && mappedValue == "testingValue")
{
    ...
}
```

Maintains readability & performance.

Here's a fiddle, courtesy of MaMazav: http://dotnetfiddle.net/2UG0QH

Also, not sure if this is an actual code sample, but you should probably use the [C# coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) for variable naming :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (ServiceLIST.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
    "testingName", "testingStatus")))
```

Comment: Great little piece of code there, very deserving of an upvote.  Still wouldnt implement it that way for readability and maintainability reasons, but full marks for making it work.  I learned something.

Comment: +1 for the positive attitude :) About readability I guess most people will agree with you, but about maintainability - in my opinion this code is more maintainable because if you have to fix the key you have to do it only once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LINQ`

```
if(ServiceLIST.Any(x => x.Key == "testingName" && x.Value == "testingStatus"))
```

Comment: kinda defeats the purpose of using a `Dictionary` doesn't it?

Comment: Naw! its creative.  I like it (+1)

Comment: Does it not change it from O(1) to O(n)?

Comment: I'm just providing alternative solution.This is not necessary, I would use `ContainsKey` either, but you can use `Any` with all collections not just Dictionary.